# Correct HTTP Headers for redirect to paypal to complete order

Tags: web-services, http, paypal, http-headers

What would be the correct http headers to use when redirecting a user to paypal in order to complete an payment?

The request goes like this:

1. Use orders something on my site
2. I take them through order process
3. They get redirected to paypal in order to authorize and pay for goods

What is the correct headers to use for the redirect in point 3?

None of the 3xx header codes seem appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

302 is perfectly fine for this.
In fact, this is the same as what PayPal uses to send the user back to your site for some API's

Your other option is to use either META tag in your HTML's head

EG: Redirect to http://example.com/ after 5 seconds:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">`

Or use the equivalent refresh header:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header